# Magento 2 : Overriding a Model file but not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

**I am getting this error always**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\IdentityInterface in C:\wamp64\www\huf\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php on line 73
```

I am overriding a Model file which is

```
Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
```

My di.xml file

```
<!--

-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" type="ABC\Listrak\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender" />
</config>
```

**My OrderSender class**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2017-2018 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved. 
 * 
**/
namespace ABC\Listrak\Model\Order\Email\Sender;

class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender
{   
    public function send(Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false)
        {
            $order->setSendEmail(true);

            if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {
                if ($this->checkAndSend($order)) {
                    $order->setEmailSent(true);
                    $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'send_email');

            return false;
        }   
}
```

**Please if someone tell me what I am doing wrong.** 
Advanced thanks.

Comment: have you run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` and cleared cache?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're extending the wrong class. Your OrderSender class should look like this

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2017-2018 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved. 
 * 
**/
namespace ABC\Listrak\Model\Order\Email\Sender;

class OrderSender extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender
{   
    public function send(Order $order, $forceSyncMode = false)
        {
            $order->setSendEmail(true);

            if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {
                if ($this->checkAndSend($order)) {
                    $order->setEmailSent(true);
                    $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
                    return true;
                }
            }

            $this->orderResource->saveAttribute($order, 'send_email');

            return false;
        }   
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks i don't know how i miss this. Thanks for your answer.